# Are there indecidable problems in probability?

Tags: probability-theory

We know that in mathematics there are some propositions which, given a set of axioms, are undecidable; and other propositions which, for what we know, might be undecidable. Are there example of these two categories in probability theory? My guess would be yes, given the set-theoretic foundations of the theory, but I could not find any concrete example. Thank you in advance for your attention.

Comment: A google search reveals the following papers:

(1) Gamarnik, David. "On deciding stability of constrained homogeneous random walks and queueing systems." *Mathematics of Operations Research* 27.2 (2002): 272-293.

(2) Gamarnik, David. "On the undecidability of computing stationary distributions and large deviation rates for constrained random walks." *Mathematics of Operations Research* 32.2 (2007): 257-265.